# Handling touches in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, touch, uitouch

I want to implement the handling of an additional swipe gesture in my UITableViewController. However, it seems that in the case of tableviews the usual touch handling methods like `-[touchesBegan::]` of the controller are not called. How can I handle touches on a UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to implement a per-row swipe gesture?  In that case, I'd override `touchesBegan` (etc.) in a custom UITableViewCell subclass (and make sure that your UITableViewDelegate does not enable the default swipe-to-delete behavior).

Otherwise, I think your best option is to overlay a custom UIView subclass over your UITableView and handle gestures there, making sure to relay any non-gesture-related events to the UITableView.